# How does a hologram record the incident laser?

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser, hologram

How does the hologram (the photographic plate) record the incident laser beams when they hit onto it, what happens **inside** the hologram so that it records these laser beams?

[image: The hologram at the end of the laser beams]

Comment: When the reference beam and the object beam come together in the plane of the hologram they interfere and form a pattern of brighter and darker areas which gets recorded by the holographic film. After the plate is developed these interference patterns are visible and can be read back with another laser or, depending on the type of the hologram, even with white light.

Comment: @CuriousOne thanks but what is the mechanism of recording I mean is the hologram just like an ordinary photographic plate? or a special photographic plate?

Comment: Holographic plates are photographic materials that are optimized for high resolution (the interference structures are the size of the wavelength, which is less than 1 micrometer) and they have to maintain dimensional stability during development and afterwards.

Comment: There's nothing special about the plate, other than the resolution, as CO wrote in his comment.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft could you clarify what you mean by "resolution"?

Comment: Resolution of photofilm (or a digital camera) refers to the smallest possible contrast element that can be recorded. Tpically this is reported in black/white line pairs/mm . If each detecting element, either digital pixel or emulsion grain, is larger than some given length, then any object in the image smaller than that will be a"blob" in the final image. This is because each grain/pixel just collects all light hitting it, with no better "reporting" of position than the dimensions of the detector.